# Opengl texture with no colour data at texture coordinate

Tags: opengl

I have a texture that I draw too in my fragment shader. When the geometry is drawn not every texture coordinate will get a colour assigned to it, because the geometry doesn't take up the entire screen space.

For example a cube in the center of your screen, you render the scene to a texture. Texture-coord(0.1,0.1) will not have any data in it ? Is that a correct assumption ? If so what data is stored in an 'empty' texture coordinate of a texture?

Comment: It has the data stored that was there before the draw call. You can use glClear, then the whole render-texture is set to the clear color.

Comment: So every slot of the texture array will contain data at all times ? It will never be uninitialized ?

Comment: It will contain some data. When you never write to it, it might contain garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you explicitly clear the texture, the data is allocated but undefined (it can be whatever). To clear the texture before drawing you can use glClear - the data will be then initialized to whatever you've set glClearColor to.